# Salvar datas com formato certo (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Utilizando o Laravel 5.8, estou a utilizar datas.
Até consigo mostrar a data com formato certo, usando `Carbon`.

```
Data de Validade {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($p->dt_validade)->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

Porém apenas consigo salvar digitando com o formato AAAA/MM/DD, gostaria de saber como poderia salvar usando o padrão DD/MM/AAAA. É possivel fazer isso direto no `controller`?

**Erro mostrado ao salvar no formato DD/MM/AAAA**

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '10/10/2012' for column 'dt_validade'

**Trecho do controller onde salva o input**

```
$produto->dt_validade = $request->input('dt_validade');
```

**Trecho da view:**

```
<div class="col-4">
    <label>Data de Validade:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-group" id="dt_validade" name="dt_validade" >
</div>
```

**Resumindo: onde eu posso declarar para salvar no formato correto?**
Obrigado.

Comment: Troque o tipo do input para `date` e experimente mostrando aqui qual o retorno do input, por favor.

Comment: dt_validade: "2080-12-31".
Com o input "date" ele salva normalmente, porém preciso usar o type text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra converter para o formato do DB, pode fazer assim:

```
'date' => Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('Y-m-d'),
```

Para para o usuario pode fazer assim:

```
   $date = Carbon::parse($variavel->date)->format('d-m-Y');
   return view('formulario', compact('date');
```

Para digitação no formato DD/MM/AAAA voce vai precisar de uma função javascript.

compartilhareditarrestaurarsinalizar

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor como faço a primeira recomendação? Como onde eu a escrevo ou se (e como) se adapta ao controller? Perdoe a ignorância.

Answer (score 1):

O método store serve para criar um registro no banco de dados pegando os dados que vem de um determinado formulário que tenha uma rota apontando para esse método do controller.

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $data = [
            'date' => Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->format('Y-m-d'), //Pegando o campo date do input que vem do formulario e convertendo ele para formato aceito pelo banco de dados

        ];

         $create = Campaign::create($data);

         if ($create){
            return redirect(route('suaview_aqui', $create->id))->with('success', trans('app.data_criada'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitua:

```
$produto->dt_validade = $request->input('dt_validade');
```

Por:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$produto->dt_validade = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('dt_validade'));
```

O Carbon fornece um método para criar datas com base em um formato, então você converte na view para exibir de forma adequada (d-m-Y), e depois que digitar e capturar pelo input você "disconverte" para o padrão (Y-m-d).

Caso ocorra algum erro pode forçar desta forma:

```
$produto->dt_validade = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('dt_validade'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

Vai depender do seu banco, se você criou um campo com formato `Date` provavelmente ele espera um `Y-m-d` pra vc salvar no formado `d/m/Y` você tera que adicionar em um campo string, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Leia as outras respostas. Sugestão de leitura: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/